# Strange SAL annotation warning

Tags: c++, annotations, compiler-warnings, sal

I'm trying to use Micosoft's SAL annotation for my project, however I get the following warning, and I don't know why.

As an example, I created a new C++ console application, and have this code:

```
#include <sal.h>

class Whatever
{
public:
    _Check_return_ int Method(__in int number) ;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile using Visual Studio 2008, I get the following warning:

warning C6540: The use of attribute annotations on this function will invalidate all of its existing __declspec annotations

In the file "c1xxast"

What am I doing wrong? If I remove either the `_Check_return_` or the `__in`, the warning goes away.

I cannot find any reference to the warning C6550. However the same text can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd445322.aspx, but it's not very helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem may be because you are mixing SAL annotation types.  Although made very clear on MSDN, there are two types of SAL annotation: attribute and ... er ... not.

The `#define`s in `<sal.h>` VC2005 use the non-attribute versions and start with an underscore followed by a **lowercase** letter. The newer VC2008 versions expand to compiler attributes and start (and end) with an underscore followed by a **capital** letter.

You have mixed the two types:

Attribute:

- _In_
- _Check_return_

Non-attribute:

- __in
- __checkReturn

Try changing your annotations to use a single type consistently.

[This blog post](http://ovidiupl.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!1E8A6038167E4BE9!660.entry) explains a bit more about this.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. No more warning !

Answer (score 1):

You must add SAL annotations to both the declaration and the definition of a method.  I'm guessing SAL's upset because it can't find the definition of the method and assumes the attributes are missing.

**EDIT** Clarification

SAL annotions must appear on both locations for non-abstract methods.  For abstract methods SAL will not look for a definition.  In certain configurations it will actually ensure that the implementation of the interface has the appropriate notations.

Comment: So that would mean SAL cannot be used with interfaces?

Comment: @Kevin, clarified my answer.  In short, SAL can be used with interfaces

Comment: @JaredPar: OK, thanks. It would seem _Check_return with __in parameters is one of those configurations, as making the method pure virtual doesn't remove the warning :(

Comment: @Kevin, interesting.  I'm going to read up a bit on that because I've not seen that behavior before.

Comment: @Kevin, have you tried adding an implementation to see if it makes the problem go away?

Comment: @JaredPar: I have just tried.
I added the declaration of a "Base" class with the pure virtual method. I then derived another class from "Base" in the header. In the sourcefile, I implemented the Derived::Method.

I now get two C6550 warnings:one for the base class declaration, and the derived class.